# When JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS will pick?

Tags: java, applet, awt

I am using java application where am using applets for some actions.I want to run one program, every time if any applet opens.I used JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to set which class should call when any applet opens.But first time applet opens, it is invoking that class,after wards for any other applets, it is not invoking.can any one help on this?How the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS works?

Answer (score 0):

You can set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS as an environment variable of the OS. On Windows 7, you can go to Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variable -> New to set the value for JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.

Comment: I have done  that only.I am asking when they will pick?not everytime when applet loads??

Comment: Whenever you launch a Java application JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS will be picked up by the JVM. How do you run your applet by browser or by command prompt?

Comment: by browser iam launching applet.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change the design of your project as follows, for the best use of Applets.
Create an Applet with your own name like "ApplicationBaseApplet" and modify the life cycle in it using the life cycle methods of Applet.
As per your requirement you keep whatever code you want to call in the `init()` method of this super class Applet.
Now, extend this Applet whenever you create new Applet. Sample code below.

```
import java.applet.Applet; // Importing Applet package

import java.awt.Graphics; // Importing Graphics package For GUI

class ApplicationBaseApplet extends Applet

{
// This method loads the applet and is only called only called once in the applet life cycle

public void init()

{
//call the code.....
}

//Applet execution starts from this method.

public void start() {

}

// This method stops or pauses the execution

public void stop() {

}

//  This method is executed  only once in the life cycle and terminates applet execution

public void destroy() {

}

// This method is used to paint the design of the applet

public void paint(Graphics g)

{

}

}
```

Now, use this Applet for all the child types.

```
import java.applet.Applet;

import java.awt.Graphics;

class FirstApplet extends ApplicationBaseApplet

{

}

import java.applet.Applet;

import java.awt.Graphics;

class SecondApplet extends ApplicationBaseApplet

{

}

import java.applet.Applet;

import java.awt.Graphics;

class ThirdApplet extends ApplicationBaseApplet

{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,but i cant change anything in that application.I just want to call my actions which i have kept in some jar,by invoking it through JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS everytime when an applet opens. Can you suggest what i need to do to achieve this, without modifying the code.